# Integrate HornetQ in Websphere Application Server

Tags: jms, websphere, message-queue, hornetq

I have been working on `Websphere Application Server` for a project, I want to integrate `HornetQ` in my Websphere Application Server.

The main objective is that I want to read/write messages from my java code running in WebSphere Application Server to the Queues that would be in HornetQ.

Please help in this regard, I was looking for support regarding this integration but couldn't find enough documentation regarding this.

How can I implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give a full solution as the resources vary widely between systems and they can be very hard to find as well, but I can provide you pointers, find them below.

1. JMS between two different systems needs adapter or JCA configuration to be in place for it to work.
2. For consuming HornetQ, you need Hornet Q resource adapter deployed into Websphere. If HornetQ did not provide the resource adapter(usuall .rar file) for websphere then you are out of luck, you have to find a more generic resource adapter for Websphere and tweak it. (there is this site where you can download the code and build rar out of it [here](http://developer-should-know.com/post/119750515302/connecting-to-remote-hornetq-server)  )
3. After deploying the resource adapter, you need to configure the resource adapter, meaning you need to let the resource adapter know the url of the HornetQ, connection factories, connection Pool size etc.
4. Write the MDB for consuming the messages from the resource adapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response, I couldn't make that work, for this reason we switched to ActiveMQ, which has a better compatibility with WebSphere.